# Problem with after/before function in jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, function, cycle

I want to fire a before function in jquery cycle. currently it just works with an after function as you can see here:
http://expostay.gtis.org/template/
(please wait 5 seconds and then you will see a arrow animation)

i want this animation to play before fading of slides starts!
but when i change "after:" to "before:" it completely freaks out:
http://expostay.gtis.org/template/index_before.html

But i dont know why??

here is the function:

```
function currentItem(curr, next, opts) { 
    var index = opts.currSlide;
    $('.tabs .innercontent').animate({"height":93},"normal",
        function(){
                    $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
                    $('.tabs a:eq('+index+')').addClass("selected");    
            $(this).animate({"height":115},"normal");
        }                                
    );
};
```

and here is the cycle code:

```
$('#slideshow a:first').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout: 3000,
            slideResize:false,
            containerResize:false,
            before: currentItem
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you should use `var index = opts.nextSlide;` or `next` instead of `var index = opts.currSlide;`... because before the the click/cycle you will get the active element. The active state for picture changes after the cycle.

Comment: yea, this was one step in the right direction i think:
http://expostay.gtis.org/template/index_before.html

seems not to work, but if you wait till it reaches the second element, it works fine. for some reason the index starts with 1 instead of 0. so it skips the first item :(

Comment: i think i found the solution:

`function currentItem(curr, next, opts) { 
 $('.tabs .innercontent').animate({"height":93},"normal",
  function(){
   var index = opts.currSlide;
   $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
   $('.tabs a:eq('+index+')').addClass("selected"); 
   $(this).animate({"height":115},"normal");
  }         
 );
};`

i had to put the index var in the callback function of the first animation!